How to make my program find the correct file
So the program is meant to read a csv file and print out the name and house of each line. However it keeps saying that it cant find my csv file even though they in the same folder.
students = []

with open("python projects/students.csv") as file:
    for line in file:
        names, house = line.rstrip().split(',')
        student = {'name': names, 'house': house }
        students.append(student)

for student in sorted(students):
    print(f"{student['name']} is in {student['house']}")

Would print out file not found

The folder from which you invoke the script is the folder that will be searched for not the folder the invoked script is contained in.

with open(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)), "python projects/students.csv"))
